# How many $2\times3$ real matrices are needed to guarantee that at least one of them is a linear combinations of the others?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The only thing I know is that

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{array}\right)$$

Seems to have a column to be linear combinations of the others.

Comment: Given that the answer is $7$, can you see why?

Comment: As $M_{2\times3}(\mathbf R)\simeq \mathbf R^6$, the minimum number is $7$.

Comment: Do you mean to ensure a column is a linear combination of the other columns?

Comment: yes, that is my question. I understand it is 7, but I am not sure why.

Comment: The reason why is that we can construct a set of six matrices where none of them is a linear combination of the other five. Perhaps given this information, you should take finding such a set of six matrices as an exercise.

Comment: Yes, its a usefull advice, I'm on it!